# Show that a process is a local martingale (Brownian bridge)

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, local-martingales, brownian-bridge

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $\{X_s\}_{t\leq s\leq1}$ be a Brownian bridge. Let we have a value function $V^*:[0,1)\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{(0,1)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by \begin{equation}
V^*(t,x)= \begin{cases}
        \sqrt{2\pi(1-t)}(1-B^2)e^{x^2/2(1-t)}\Phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-t}}), & \text{if } x<b(t) \\
       x, & \text{if } x\geq b(t)
        \end{cases},
\end{equation}
for $t<1$ and $V(1,0)=0$, where $b(t)=B\sqrt{1-t}$.

Lets show that $M_s=\int_{t}^{s}V_x^*(u,X_u)I(X_u\neq b(u))dW_u$ is a local martingal. In fact, since $V_x^*$ is bounded, the proces $M$ is a martingale.

Are there ''standard'' routes to follow when trying to prove that a process is/isn't a local martingale? How can I prove this for my case?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A process $\int_0^T H_tdB_t$ is a square-integrable martingale if $\int_0^T \mathbb E[H_t^2]dt<\infty$. If we only have $\int_0^T H_t^2dt<\infty$ almost-surely, then the process is in general only a local martingale. You can look up the basic theory of such stochastic integrals in Baldi's "Stochastic Calculus" Chapter 7.

Comment: So you suggest me to proove that $\int_{0}^{T}V_x^{*2}(u,X_u)I(X_u\neq b(u))dW_u <\infty$?

Comment: This would prove that it is a local martingale, correct. If you want to prove that it is a proper (square-integrable) martingale, you may want to show that $\mathbb E[\int_0^T (V_x^*)^2(u,X_u)I(X_u\neq b(u))du]<\infty$. You were already given the fact that $V$ is bounded, so this should be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.